# npm install interrupts without error indication

Tags: node.js, npm

There is `package.json` below.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

And as a result of executing `npm install`, the processing ends in the middle as shown below, and no error is displayed.

```
c:\test>npm install --loglevel=verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel=verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v8.10.0
npm verb npm-session f1e5e2cf3695876a
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~preinstall: test@0.0.0
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasminewd2 767ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter 779ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine 784ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 803ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp 825ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 837ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 846ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 858ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ng-bootstrap%2fng-bootstrap 864ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2flanguage-service 882ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib 133ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode 892ms
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-07886ea4c957ccb4.lock for c:\test\node_modules\.staging
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-1.9.0.tgz 170ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jasmine/-/jasmine-2.8.6.tgz 312ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jasminewd2/-/jasminewd2-2.0.3.tgz 721ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-6.0.103.tgz 863ms

c:\test>
```

Repeat `npm install` several times afterwards to complete successfully.

```
c:\test>npm install --loglevel=verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel=verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v8.10.0
npm verb npm-session 6156e805bb2b7ef7
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~preinstall: test@0.0.0
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 390ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 424ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 430ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib 162ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ng-bootstrap%2fng-bootstrap 740ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter 759ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasminewd2 776ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp 797ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 804ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine 837ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2flanguage-service 849ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode 668ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine 305ms (from cache)
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-07886ea4c957ccb4.lock for c:\test\node_modules\.staging
npm info lifecycle @types/jasmine@2.8.6~preinstall: @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.9.0~preinstall: tslib@1.9.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/core@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/core@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/forms@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/http@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/http@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/language-service@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/router@5.2.9~preinstall: @angular/router@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4~preinstall: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm info lifecycle @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3~preinstall: @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle @types/node@6.0.103~preinstall: @types/node@6.0.103
npm info linkStuff @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm verb linkBins @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm verb linkMans @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm info linkStuff tslib@1.9.0
npm verb linkBins tslib@1.9.0
npm verb linkMans tslib@1.9.0
npm info linkStuff @angular/core@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/core@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/core@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/http@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/http@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/http@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @angular/router@5.2.9
npm verb linkBins @angular/router@5.2.9
npm verb linkMans @angular/router@5.2.9
npm info linkStuff @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm verb linkBins @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm verb linkMans @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm info linkStuff @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm verb linkBins @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm verb linkMans @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm info linkStuff @types/node@6.0.103
npm verb linkBins @types/node@6.0.103
npm verb linkMans @types/node@6.0.103
npm info lifecycle @types/jasmine@2.8.6~install: @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.9.0~install: tslib@1.9.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/core@5.2.9~install: @angular/core@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/forms@5.2.9~install: @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/http@5.2.9~install: @angular/http@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/language-service@5.2.9~install: @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9~install: @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9~install: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/router@5.2.9~install: @angular/router@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4~install: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm info lifecycle @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3~install: @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle @types/node@6.0.103~install: @types/node@6.0.103
npm info lifecycle @types/jasmine@2.8.6~postinstall: @types/jasmine@2.8.6
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.9.0~postinstall: tslib@1.9.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/core@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/core@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/forms@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/forms@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/http@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/http@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/language-service@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/language-service@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @angular/router@5.2.9~postinstall: @angular/router@5.2.9
npm info lifecycle @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4~postinstall: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4
npm info lifecycle @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3~postinstall: @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle @types/node@6.0.103~postinstall: @types/node@6.0.103
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-07886ea4c957ccb4.lock for c:\test\node_modules\.staging
npm info linkStuff test@0.0.0
npm verb linkBins test@0.0.0
npm verb linkMans test@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~install: test@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~postinstall: test@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~prepublish: test@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@0.0.0~prepare: test@0.0.0
npm verb saving []
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.9 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@5.2.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@5.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@5.2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@5.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@5.2.9 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@5.2.9 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN test@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@0.0.0 No repository field.

added 12 packages in 4.842s
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok

c:\test>
```

My environment is as follows.

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Node.js: v8.10.0
- npm: 5.6.0

It does not occur in the environment of a colleague connected to the same network.
(We are doing `npm cache clean` and`rm - rf node_modules` on verification in colleague environment.
Also, since it is connected to the same network, it seems that it is not a network related phenomenon. )

- It seems to be completed at the end as cash is accumulated little by little by every execution.
- Similar events occur on RHEL servers with different operating systems and networks.
- I believe that the situation is similar to the issue below.
  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13729
- I tried using `yarn`, but a similar event occurred.

Is there anyone else who is experiencing similar events?

I would be pleased if you could tell me how to deal with that case.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue few days ago and I was running out of RAM memory . Try upgrading the memory or free up some space  and reinstall the node modules again!!

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I restarted the PC and tried again when the RAM status was the following, but the same phenomenon did not work.

- Total: 8 GB
- In use: 4.5 GB
- Available: 3.5 GB

I was watching "Task Manager" while executing npm install, but there was no way that memory usage spiked.
(The amount of memory used during execution increased from 100 MB to 200 MB)